# Change the path of application in Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, contextpath

I have my web application whose name is `myApp.war`. I copy my war file in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`. Now I can open my site using the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/
```

However I want to change the path of my application (for example: `newName`), so I add a file `ROOT.xml` in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost`.

Here is the code :

```xml
<Context docBase="myApp" path="/newName" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
```

Now I use the new URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/newName/
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Add the line below in your `server.xml`:

```xml
<Context docBase="myApp" path="/newName" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
```

Like:

```xml
<Host>
  .
  .
  .
  <Context docBase="myApp" path="/newName" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
</Server>
```

I would suggest another approach by using the Apache web server. Edit `httpd.conf` and write:

```
ProxyPass /newName http://localhost:8080/myApp
ProxyPassReverse /newName http://localhost:8080/myApp
```

You can access your app by `http://localhost/newName`.

**Note:** Apache runs on port 80 so you don't need to give the port number after `localhost` while accessing.

Comment: but in the document of Tomcat it says : For Tomcat 6, unlike Tomcat 4.x, it is NOT recommended to place <Context> elements directly in the server.xml file. This is because it makes modifying the Context configuration more invasive since the main conf/server.xml file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat. @neonleo

Comment: Hi marssteve, because of this reason, i have provided a solution by using apache web server. You can paste two line of code that i have written and access by the mentioned URL. Any xml configuration change in server would ask for restart to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming ROOT.xml to newName.xml and put it in "$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost" folder. Tomcat tries to find the same appName and xml file.
I hope it was useful for your request.

[Tomcat 6 Documentation - Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

See Introduction title:
"[...]In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The name of the file (less the .xml extension) will be used as the context path[...]"

Told me if it works,
Regards.

Sorry about my english!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added NewName directory in the tomcat webapps path and copied the content to it? I hope that should resolve your issue.